# AWS Cloudfront - do you have to enable other regions?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, cdn

we have a server running on Google Cloud Run in the eastern US serving a small web app to our internal users in NY and manufacturers in China. Site runs very slow in China so I set up cloudfront cdn. Now users in China are hitting a Cloudfront server in San Francisco. Do I have to explicitly enable the Asia region to have the site cached there?

Answer (score 1):

[image: Price Class]

I think you should change the Price Class to include Asia or best is all edge location to have best performance in Cloudfront settings